# More Night Furies? Could there be more?

Tags: how-to-train-your-dragon

What do you think would happen if Hiccup and Toothless find more Night Furies?
Would they accept Toothless the way that he is?

Comment: It is likely the community will close this question since it does not follow the guidelines for questions. Your question is very speculative and would require answers not covered by the movies or books. Please refer to our help guide to better phrase your question in a format more likely to get an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well from what we've been given, *the* Night Fury is obviously Toothless, but if there are others just like Toothless, they would probably follow the footsteps of the other dragons to domestication of the people of Berk. Good question though! Keep speculating! :)